# Replace an html element in a plain text string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a plain string:

```
var text = '<p>hello</p> <iframe src="http://whatever.com/1"></iframe><iframe src="http://notsosure.com"></iframe><iframe src="http://whatever.com/2"></iframe><p>goodby</p>'
```

I need to remove each iframe from the string starting with `src=http://whatever.com` and replace them with a link pointing to the same url.

I thought I could do something like this with jQuery:

```
$text = $(text)
$text
    .find("iframe[src^='http://whatever.com']")
    .replaceWith('<a href="' + $( this ).attr('src') + '"> Click Here</a>')
```

But this doesn't work as it return the replaced string and it doesn't modify my original $text object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track using an HTML parser, not naive text processing using a regular expression ([obligatory link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454)). Just a couple of things:

- Your structure may have `iframe`s at the top level, but `find` won't find them there.
- You have to keep going: Turn it back into a string.

So for instance (see comments):

```js
var text = '<p>hello</p> <iframe src="http://whatever.com/1"></iframe><iframe src="http://notsosure.com"></iframe><iframe src="http://whatever.com/2"></iframe><p>goodby</p>';
// Put them in a wrapper for convenience, so we don't have to worry about iframe
// elements at the top level
var wrapper = $("<div>");
wrapper.append(text);
// Find and replace the relevant iframe elements
wrapper.find("iframe[src^='http://whatever.com']").each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($("<a>").attr("href", this.src));
});
// Turn it back into text
text = wrapper.html();
console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```